# Ubuntu doesn’t load after install NVIDIA graphic drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I have installed NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 11.10. I have referred following article which describes [“The Advanced Way of installing Nvidia Drivers in Ubuntu (only recommended if you need the latest drivers or run a custom kernel.)”](http://www.overclock.net/a/install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-11-04-11-10).

It was installed successfully but unfortunately ubuntu doesn’t load. 
When I started my laptop it stops in a screen that says me

```
*(...)
* Starting bluetooth
* PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions
 saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned)

*Stopping save kernal messages      [OK]
*Starting CUPS printing spooler/server  [OK]

*(...)
Checking for running unattended-upgrades:
*Stopping Failsafe boot delay       [OK]
*(…)
*Starting deferred execution scheduler  [OK]
```

Then it’s hanging on and doesn’t go forward.

My graphic driver is NVIDIA Geforce GT525M and 64bit DELL inspiron n5110 laptop.

I would appreciate if anybody can give advice on this matter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: its 'Ubuntu', not 'ubantu' Edited now.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes installing NVIDIA drivers causes problems with the xorg.conf file. You may want to rename /etc/X11/xorg.conf (or remove it). Then you´ve to restart your system. At boot time Ubuntu will create a new xorg.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that, but this happens some times with Ubuntu. It also happened to me when I was new to Ubuntu, and installed some drivers (but it was my fault).
I reinstalled the system, it was the easyest way, and on the other hand, installig is faster then windows.

Comment: your comment doesn't seem to answer the question directly. Re-installing should be the last to consider, only if all else fails.